# Javascript: OnChange not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox that sets the onchange property but when i start typing in the textbox the onchange doesnt fire initially. it never fires whats going on?

Here is the code:

VB.NET

```
      Dim textBoxUrlYoutube As New TextBox
      divUrlTextBoxContainer.Controls.Add(textBoxUrlYoutube)
      textBoxUrlYoutube.CssClass = "textboxyoutubeurlmediaselector"
      textBoxUrlYoutube.Attributes.Add("onchange", 
                                       "YoutubeUrlSaveTextBoxOnChange(this)")
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function YoutubeUrlSaveTextBoxOnChange(el) {

    var text = $(el).val();

    if (text == '') {

        $("a.linkplayyoutubeurl2").attr("class", "linkplayyoutubeurl1");
        $("div.divlinktext2").attr("class", "divlinktext1");

    }
    else {

        $("a.linkplayyoutubeurl1").attr("class", "linkplayyoutubeurl2");
        $("div.divlinktext1").attr("class", "divlinktext2");
    }

}
```

Comment: For problems with JavaScript interacting with HTML, show HTML and JavaScript … not server side code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change events fire when the focus is lost, if a change has occurred.

If you want a change to fire with every keypress, use the keypress event.

Comment: Doward the problem with this keypress is that when you initally type a letter in te textbox the kepress event returns the text of the textbox to empty. i need a function that gets the value as sonn as the first charachter is typed in the textbox

Comment: Or these days more than 11 years later, the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).